# Navigating to a page before login is not working

Tags: jsf-2

I want to set-up my data before loading first page in to session.

My XHTML:

```
<f:event listener="#{beforeLogin.setup}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
```

My Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="beforeLogin")
@RequestScoped
public class BeforeLogin {
   public void setup()
   {
    .....
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("Key1", "Value1");
    ....
   ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context
            .getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
   nav.performNavigation("LoginPage");
   }
}
}
```

Now in my `LoginPage`, under `PostConstruct` method, I'm getting `Key1` value as `null` from session. Can any one suggest where Im doing the mistake? Note: I tried even with `SessionScope` for the `BeforeLogin` bean.

Comment: How are you attempting to retrieve the value in `LoginPage`?

Comment: Does it matter? any way... FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("Key1")

Comment: It obviously matters, how could it not? What if you for example copy pasted and had the wrong map.

Comment: Yeah. It is my mistake. I was killing the session at another place by mistake. Issue is resolved. Thanks.